# Some faces not showing in modelling, but visible in sculpting mode

Tags: modeling

I'm pretty new to blender. I was working on a model, and after some accidental key typing, I can only see some faces of my model in modelling mode, however, in layout and any mode that won't clearly show vertices, I have no problem seeing the faces. here are some pictures to illustrate
Hope you can help me and thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have accidentally deleted edges & faces (`X` then `Only Edges and Faces`).  If that's the case you need to undo or go back to an earlier backup.

But just to make sure, I suggest pressing `Alt + H` (`Reveal Hidden`) in edit mode first.